# PackageManager.getInstalledApplications(0); in Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-package-managers

My problem is that I use package manager to list all the installed applications

```
final PackageManager pm = parentActivity.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

With this code I can list successfully all the applications in other versions of android except in `Android 7.0` (which only list the app that I'm using), can anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. It is working fine for me:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
    Log.d("APP_INFO", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);
}
```

Tested on **Android 6, 7 and 8**

Hope this will help!

Comment: After some time I realized the list was not the problem, the problem is trafficStats that gives me negative numbers, but thank you so much